# Search and replace string with reverse

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find words in a string and replace them with themselves in reverse-form.
So, when I have `This 17`, I want to put out `sihT 17`.

But I don't know how to reverse the string itself in `re.sub()`

```
import re

pat_word = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")
input = raw_input ("Input: ")

match = pat_word.findall(input)
if match: 
    s = re.sub(pat_word, "reverse", input)
    print s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function inside `re.sub`:

```
s = re.sub(pat_word, lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], input)
```

Or simply:

```
s = pat_word.sub(lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], input)
```

From `help(re.sub)`:

> sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
>    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
>    replacement repl.  **repl can be either a string or a callable**;
>    if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
>    a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
>    a replacement string to be used.

<sub>Note that `input` is a built-in function in Python, so don't use it as  a variable name.</sub>

Comment: @Saphire You don't have groups in your regex, and by default [group(0)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) returns the entire match.  BTW you can simply use: `pat_word.sub(lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], input)` here.